# Validate URL - URL is Valid without TLD?

Tags: php, validation

So, I have an input box where someone can input a URL. When they submit the forum, I would like it to check if it is a valid URL.

Now, my problem is that "http://someurl" (without the TLD) is valid, and "someurl.com" or "www.someurl.com" is not valid (without the http://). Is there a way to fix this?

```
$input = 'someurl.com'; // Could also be an IP

if (filter_var($input, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP)) {
    echo "IP Valid";
} else if (filter_var($input, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)) {
    echo "URL Valid";
} else {
    echo "Not an IP or URL";
}
```

Comment: Of course a URL is valid without a TLD; this includes the use of aliases (eg. "localhost" and machines on a local/corporate network) and literal IP addresses. Now, there is different between a URL being valid and a URL referring to a valid [and reachable] resource .. the only way to know the latter is to *use* the URL in a meaningful way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fix is to insert `http://` yourself as an URL *must* have a scheme. This is why the simple `www.someurl.com` is invalid: it doesn't have a scheme.

URL without top-level domains are perfectly fine, like `http://localhost`. In a LAN with correctly set [search domain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resolv.conf) you also can use URLs without a domain: for example, if the search domain of your company is `somecompany.com` and you have the URL `http://fileserver`, your system will internally build the fully qualified domain name `fileserver.somecompany.com`. Some URLs don't have hosts at all (for example, `tel:`), BTW.

Comment: @Xero: Telephone. Used to dial a number. Most smartphones support it. E. g `tel:+123456789`.